# how can i delete the 1st string from each line in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I read a text file and add the value to array, then I match a string to that array.
If it matches, I want the last value of each line to show.
There are two value separated by comma, I want to show the last value.

```
$lines = file("D:/CameraName.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $dev) !== false) {
        !$found = true ;
        $dispname=  //here iwant the code to see the last value of each line  
        echo $dispname ;
    }
}
```

Contents of the file:

```
1234,abcd11
1235,avce21
```

Comment: Please show an example of your file. What  is "the last value of each line" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use explode() to split the line at the comma and array_pop() to get the last item.

```
$lines = file("D:/CameraName.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $dev) !== false) {
        !$found = true;
        $lineValues = explode(',', $line);
        $dispname = array_pop($lineValues);
        echo $dispname;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to show the last value of each line, as from his question: * if it matches i want the last value of each line to show*

Comment: With array_pop OP will get the last value.

Comment: BTW: Your code will give you: *Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference*

Comment: if not found what to do

Comment: @Rizier123 changed the code to use an intermediate variable.

Comment: @TOM What do you mean? If not found, the condition won't be TRUE and nothing will be printed. If you want to do something, if the condition is FALSE, add an else block.

Comment: when i put else , it print all the names

Comment: Please update your question adding your current code and tell us what should happen if the line doesn't match. You didn't tell us by now.